# Can I fit Audi 4000 compatible shock absorbers onto my Audi 80 B2 1.6D?

Tags: audi, shock-absorber

I have an european Audi 80 B2 with the following parameters:

```
Type: Audi 80 B2 1.6 GL Diesel
Capacity: 1588cc
Performance: 40kw
Year: 1982
Motor code: CR
```

I want to buy a new set of shock absorbers for the car. [This](http://gabriel.com/product-search/light-vehicle/?yr=1982&make=Audi&model=4000&engine=) USA made absorbers will fit Audi 4000 from 1982 (the american export of the Audi 80). Are they fit on my car?

I want a good quality shock absorber for the car which not breaking the bank (eg. set of 4 will be no more than the price of the car...) and giving me good stability on rough roads and in turns for maximum comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool car! The shock absorbers for an 1982 *Audi 4000* should fit an 1982 *Audi 80* - the 4000 is pretty much an 80 with some slight body changes for the US market (I believe bumpers, trims and lights).

However do take a look at the year closely, if I remember correctly there was an updated model in production between 1984 and 1986. The platform is still considered B2, but there *might* be some slight suspension differences, not entirely sure about that.